# Use Tile view only for top level of Document Set?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, document-set, sitepages

I have a Document Set defined and I created a default view on the library using the Tiles format, so it appears like this:

[image]

I want to have it so that when I click on the tile representing the Document Set, it switches to the normal folder/file view ("List") of a document library, like:

[image]

However, it always stays in the Tiles view.

I have a view I created "Tiles" and I made that the default view. In the view config, under "Folders", I have "Show items inside folders" and for "Show this View" I selected "In the top-level folder". It will not allow me to select "In folders of content type" - it is grayed out.

I created another view "Library" and under "Folders" for "Show this view" I selected "in folders of content type" and selected "Folder".

Then I put the Document Library web part on a page. It defaults to the Tiles view, but when I click on a Tile, it stays in the Tiles view - it does not switch to the "Library" view to just show the files and folders without the tiles.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint site page and open it in edit mode using "Edit" option at the top right corner
2. Add new **Library** web part on the page
3. In web part settings, select the view you formatted with "Tiles" view.
4. Apply the changes to web part settings
5. Publish/Republish the page
6. It will show the tiles like this:

   [image]
7. Then **double click** on the document set tile, which will open the library web part in normal table view structure like:

   [image]

---

Also, to select the specific content type under "In folders of content type" settings, you first have to select the radio button at the left:

[image]

If you go to List settings --> View section it will show your view like:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

I have 2 views in the document library:

1. All Documents - Default view in the library shown in Tiles format and same view is selected in the Library web part settings on site page
2. Admin View

**Settings for All Documents**:

[image]

**Settings for Admin View**:

[image]

Comment: That's where the disconnect is for me. On your step 7, if I double-click on the document set tile, it does not open it in the normal list view. It stays in Tile mode.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine for me. Do you have "Admin View" in your document library? If yes, set the "Folders" options as shown in the last image in my answer. If no, create a new view and set the folders options. Select: `In folders of content type: Document Set`.

Comment: OK, so here is what KIND OF works for me. I created a view "Tiles", set "Show this View" to "In folders of content type" and selected the content type of my Document Set., and added that web part to the page. I created a view called "Library" that is the List format and made that the Default View and chose "In the top-level folder". Now on the web part page, it shows the Tile View and a click on a tile switches to Library View. BUT... if I click on the name of the Doc Library in the breadcrumbs to get back to the root, it doesn't go back to Tile View. I have to refresh the page to get back.

Comment: In my case, it goes back to Tiles view without any issues. I will update view settings and screenshots in my answer.

Comment: So in your example, when you double click on the document set tile, then click on "DocumentSets" in the breadcrumbs, it goes back to tiles?

Comment: yes, correct. Check the view details and settings in my updated answer. Note: All Documents view is set in Tiles format, also set as default view in the library and selected the same view in Library web part added on site page.

Comment: How are you setting the All Documents view to Tiles format? Don't you need to do a Save As to a different view to save the tile view as the default?

Comment: It will not save All Documents in Tile format for me.

Comment: Go to All Documents view --> Select Tiles format from view options drop down --> Again click on view options drop down and select "Save view as" --> from "Save as" popup **do not change** the name of view and just click "Save". It will save the same All Documents view as Tiles format.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get that. but I am still not able to get it to work like you say. I can get it to switch from Tile view to List view when I double-click on the Tile, but I can't get back to the Tile view without refreshing the page. It stays in the List view after that first double-click. I'm putting the web part on a site page.

Comment: I am also using the library web part on site page (you can see the page command bar in my 1st image). Did you set same view settings as shown in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have the views the same. All Documents, set as default view, saved in Tiles format. Admin view, not default, saved in List format. When I put that on a page, it initially displays the tiles (All Documents) but when I double-click on a tile, it stays in the tile format (view stays as All Documents). If I make the Admin view the default view, the page then starts in All Documents (tiles), double-click switches to Admin (list), but clicking the root of the breadcrumbs stays in the Admin view (list). Only a page refresh gets the root back to tiles.